# What does it mean for $\max_{1\leq{i}\leq{n}}x_i-1<\theta<\min_{1\leq{i}\leq{n}}x_i$?

Tags: real-analysis, linear-algebra

Suppose we have that $x_1,...,x_n$ are values $\in \mathbb{R}$.

Here is the following problem:

[image: Question and Answer:]

1) How is it possible to have $\max_{1\leq{i}\leq{n}}x_i-1<\theta<\min_{1\leq{i}\leq{n}}x_i$?
How can a value of $\theta$ be both greater than a larger value and less than a smaller value? Isn't that contradictory?

2) How is it that $\max_{1\leq{i}\leq{n}}x_i-1 < \min_{1\leq{i}\leq{n}}x_i $?

For example, what if my $\max_{1\leq{i}\leq{n}}x_i = 10$ and $\min_{1\leq{i}\leq{n}}x_i = 1$? Would this then mean that $10<1$?

3) Finally, if $x_1,...,x_n= 1,0,1,0,1,0,...,1,0$, where the maximum is $1$ and the minimum is $0$, wouldn't it mean that $0<\theta<0$ and so implies that $\theta = 0$ and thus is unique?

Thanks everyone!!!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to read again to understand what's going on :

X1, ... will be "evaluated" with values in $(\theta, \theta + 1)$ (the $x_i$), so $min x_i > \theta$ and $max x_i < \theta + 1$

I pick $\theta = 2.3$ for instance, and imagine I don't tell you that. Then I will pick n random variables in (2.3, 3.3). And I give you these numbers (e.g n=3 and x1=2.7, x2=2.4, x3=2.9) and you have to try to find what could be the $\theta$ I chose. So you know it is smaller than 2.4 and bigger than 1.9

I let you get this first then you can ask for other hints for the other questions, but getting the problem should be a big step forward

Comment: I see, so you are basically saying that I sort of "fix" $\theta$ first, then determine what happens to the x.

For problem 2, is it that the relation holds because we said that x was between $\theta$ and $\theta + 1$, thereby making it so that values of x will be within 1 of each other?

Finally, for problem 3, this example cannot be used since we said that since x was contained in the STRICT inequality, that the difference between the max and min is LESS than 1?

Comment: yes, you "fix" it "in your mind". Do you see why question 2 is not possible ? (with max = 10 and min= 1)

Comment: and why question 3 is "true" ?

Comment: I just edited my earlier, question, am i on the right track?

Comment: I am not sure what is your question, but 3 is true indeed, I was asking if you understood why

Comment: For problem 2, is it that the relation holds because we said that x was between θ and θ+1, thereby making it so that values of x will be within 1 of each other? Finally, for problem 3, this example cannot be used since we said that since x was contained in the STRICT inequality, that the difference between the max and min is LESS than 1? Are these the right reasons? Thanks!!!

Comment: you are right

About problem 3, the intuition is correct. Just imagine that x1=0.000001 and x2=0.999999 which imply that $\theta$ is in between 0 and 0.0000001 or something. As you say you will obtain an interval, not a single $\theta$